# Earth/ground on a Photax photographic light

Tags: lighting

U.K. electric question

I've got an aluminium Photax clamp on light. It only has 2 core wire, and no earthing/ground wire, nor any earth/ground connection point. I presume they were made in the days before earth wires were required. Do people now earth these types of lights.

The lamp is similar to  [this](https://www.drewpritchard.co.uk/products/photax-light) (show below):

[image]

If so how do they do so elegantly, without it looking like a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely must rewire the lamp with preferably heat resistant 3-core flex (those bulbs can get hot!) If you are not 100% confident you can do a safe job, you should entrust the job to a skilled electrician.

Those brass lampholders (inc. nickel plated ones like in your linked pic) can be had with an earthing screw. You can change the holder and make sure the earth wire is properly attached using the screw terminal. To clarify, the first picture below is a colour one (the brass is nickel plated). The second one shows the manner of wiring (but the holder is an unplated brass one). The blue & brown covered wires to the terminals of the bayonet pins, and the third green/yellow earth wire to the earthing terminal,and the screw properly tightened.

[image]

[image]